# Ignoring duplicate

Tags: product, category, ce-1.9.1.0

So i am trying to run a query to move product from category 650 into 652.

This query runs successfully if no duplicate exists.

```
INSERT INTO catalog_category_product( category_id, product_id, position ) (

SELECT 652 , product_id, position
FROM catalog_category_product
WHERE category_id
IN ( 650 )
)
```

However, if duplicate exist.. i get duplicate error.

What query do i need to add to tell it to ignore the duplicate and copy the other products?

please help me and write the specific line that i should ad.. i am mysql illiterate.

i hear something about insert ignore into

Comment: Could you please clarify why you seek to insert rows when you actually want to update the field `category_id` on existing entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO 
    catalog_category_product( category_id, product_id, position ) 
    (
        SELECT 652 , product_id, position
        FROM catalog_category_product
        WHERE category_id IN ( 650 )
    )
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE category_id = 652
```